# Keyboard navigation in Telerik WPF RadCarousel

Tags: wpf, telerik

I'm struggling a bit with keyboard navigation in the Telerik WPF RadCarousel. If i click outside an item, but within the carousel-control, keyboard naviation works as expected (I can switch between items using the left and right keyboard arrows), but if I click an item within the RadCarousel, keyboard navigation is gone. How can I get the RadCarousel to handle keyboard navigation when an item in the carousel has focus?

Additional things I want to accomplish:

1. Automatically show the SelectedItem as the "front-item" in the carousel.
2. Automatically select the "front-item" when navigating through the carousel.

My RadCarousel binding is set up as follows:

```
    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="true">
        <telerik:RadCarousel Name="carousel" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Templates}"
                             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template}"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTemplateAndFolder}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Edit:

By using Snoop, I can see that the "CarouselScrollViewer" has focus when the scrolling is working. Selecting an item causes the RadCarousel to get focus (and the navigation to stop working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the most import things to work, which was the keyboard navigation and moving the selected item to the front of the carousel.

1. Keyboard navigation:

   ```
   private void Carousel_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       CarouselScrollViewer scrollViewer = FindChild<CarouselScrollViewer>(this.carousel, null);


   scrollViewer.Focus();


   }


   public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
      where T : DependencyObject
   {
       // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
       if (parent == null) return null;


   T foundChild = null;


   int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
   for (int i = 0; i &lt; childrenCount; i++)
   {
       var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
       // If the child is not of the request child type child
       T childType = child as T;
       if (childType == null)
       {
           // recursively drill down the tree
           foundChild = FindChild&lt;T&gt;(child, childName);


           // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
           if (foundChild != null) break;
       }
       else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
       {
           var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
           // If the child's name is set for search
           if (frameworkElement != null &amp;&amp; frameworkElement.Name == childName)
           {
               // if the child's name is of the request name
               foundChild = (T)child;
               break;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           // child element found.
           foundChild = (T)child;
           break;
       }
   }


   return foundChild;


   }
   ```
2. Moving selected item into center of carousel:

   ```
   private void Carousel_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangeEventArgs e)
   {
       this.carousel.BringDataItemIntoView(this.carousel.CurrentItem);
   }
   ```